# Changing cell colour background in Excel using a public VBA function - not a VBA programmer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, background-color

I want to change the fill colour of a cell, based on a value in another cell. This will be a series implementation, e.g. A1, based on value in B1; A2, based on value in B2 and so on.

I want to use a public function so I can use it this way and pull down for the series implementation.

`IF(B1>0,ColourCell("A1","Green"),IF(B1<0,ColourCell("A1","Red",ColourCell("A1","White"))))`

I don't know data types, etc. in VB - can I have some help please to get it working in VB.
I have inserted a module (General). This is what the function is.

```
Public Function ColourCell(cell, colour)

If colour = "Green" Then

    Range("cell").Interior.Color = vbGreen

ElseIf colour = "Red" Then

    Range("cell").Interior.Color = vbRed

ElseIf colour = "White" Then

    Range("cell").Interior.Color = vbWhite

End If

End Function
```

My understanding is that once it all works, I can use it in the way described.

Thanks

Comment: UDFs can't (except in some edge cases) change another cell. Nor can they change the formatting of the cell they are called from.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: You could use a sub with arguments.

Comment: I have tried. I can't use conditionally formatting in this way.

Comment: SJR - That is what I need help with to write up the sub/public function with the right data types etc. so it will execute in VB and work in Excel sheet.

Comment: What issues do you have with conditionally formatting? Seems to me rather easy. Just create 3 rules based on simple formula, eg `=B1>0`

Answer (score 2):

To circumvent the problem mentioned by BigBen here is another approach.

You need to remove the quotes around `cell` as otherwise it will be treated as a literal string.

Good practice too to declare argument types in your function.

There's no error trapping here, e.g. for invalid ranges.

```
Sub ColourCell(cell As String, colour As String)

If colour = "Green" Then
    Range(cell).Interior.Color = vbGreen
ElseIf colour = "Red" Then
    Range(cell).Interior.Color = vbRed
ElseIf colour = "White" Then
    Range(cell).Interior.Color = vbWhite
End If

End Sub
```

---

Call the sub this way:

```
Sub x()

ColourCell "A1", "Green"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you SJR - I will have a go.